# Getting dropdown value from system.xml issue in Magento

Tags: magento-1, system.xml

This is part of my system.xml:

```
<config>
    <sections>
            <mynamespace_mymodule translate="label" module="mynamespace_mymodule">
        .....
                    <groups>
                       <display translate="label" module="mynamespace_mymodule">
                            <label>Display settings</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                            <fields>
                                <showlinks translate="label">
                                    <label>Custom Text</label>
                                    <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                                    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                                    <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                                </showlinks>
                            </fields>
                        </display>
                     </groups>
                 </mynamespace_mymodule>
            </sections>
</config>
```

This is how I got the value from my dropdown:

```
Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('mynamespace_mymodule/display/showlinks', 1)
```

and the results is always `false`. I checked the value from db and it is `1` or `yes`. The selected value is `yes` but it always returns me NOT `null` but `false`. Why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your updated code:

```
  <config>
<sections>
        <mycustommodule translate="label" module="mynamespace_mymodule">
    .....
                <groups>
                   <display translate="label" module="mynamespace_mymodule">
                        <label>Display settings</label>
                        <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                        <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        <fields>
                            <showlinks translate="label">
                                <label>Custom Text</label>
                                <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                                <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                                <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            </showlinks>
                        </fields>
                    </display>
                 </groups>
             </mycustommodule>
        </sections>
```

your code for store configuration.

```
Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('mycustommodule/display/showlinks', 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get system configuration use this code:

```
 Mage::getStoreConfig('sections/groups/fields',Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
```

so in your case

section is may be wrong.

```
Mage::getStoreConfig('mynamespace_mymodule/display/showlinks', 1);
```

If you want to use same function than

```
 Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('mynamespace_mymodule/display/showlinks', 1)
```

Comment: I updated my post , my xml. Most probably its  wrong name in the xml or smth. But I am too blind to see it. Can you check my update? thnx